# UIPickerView's UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't fire

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipickerview

I've a `UITableViewCell` with a `UIPickerView`. I wanted to catch the event of taping on 1 element (so not what 
`pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` does)

Here is my class:

```
class PickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var pickerView:UIPickerView!

    private var gestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap:")
        gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        pickerView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func didTap(gestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")
    }

    override func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

As suggested in other responses I overrode `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`'s method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer`to return true but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add set the delegate of my `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

did the job since I already overrode `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer`!